# Polymorphic Associations not saving values

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My models:

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :itemable
  belongs_to :itemable, polymorphic: true

  belongs_to :lead
  belongs_to :cart


end

class House < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items, :as => :itemable
end

class Appartment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items, :as => :itemable
end
```

line_item_controller:

```
def create
      @line_item = @cart.line_items.build item: @object
      respond_to do |format|
        if @line_item.save
          format.html { redirect_to @line_item.cart,
            notice: 'Vakantiehuis toegevoegd in lijst.' }
          format.json { render action: 'show',
            status: :created, location: @line_item }
        else
          format.html { render action: 'new' }
          format.json { render json: @line_item.errors,
            status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
   end

private
    def create_object
      id = params[:house_id] || params[:appartment_id]

      model = "House" if params[:house_id]
      model = "Apartment" if params[:apartment_id]
      model = model.constantize

      @object = model.find(id)
   end
```

When a new item list is created the values in de table line_items (itemable_id, itemable_type) are not saved. What am i doing wrong here? thanks..remco

Comment: instead `model="House"` and `model.constantize` you could directly write `model=House`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try replace:

```
@cart.line_items.build item: @object
```

to:

```
@cart.line_items.build itemable: @object
```

Comment: after i add a house or appartment to the list...the visitor redirects to the cart...in the show template i have a loop with all the items @cart.line_items.each do |item| But how can i link in the loop to the related house or appartment?

Comment: you could just write: `link_to item.itemable`